# Why can't disk utility make images of some kinds of DVD's / CD's?

Tags: dvd, osx-el-capitan

According to the license terms of my DVD's (software, not video), I am allowed to make a copy for backup purposes.

Disk utility seems to have no problem making images (DVD / CD master option), for discs from 90's. But for disks in the early 2000's, it seems to fail with error code 5.

I have googled extensively what "error code 5" is, and there seems to be no answer on the inter web what error code 5 is. I can only guess that this error seems to have something to do with these particular DVD's produced in early 2000's. The disks themselves are scratch free, and work fine (they are practically unused). If this means the disks are DRM'd, then how am I supposed to make a backup ?

Comment: have you tried different image making software, or different PCs?

Comment: well, if its DRM's, per the MPAA, if you want a backup, you should buy another copy of the disk, and if its out of print, that's just how the rights holder has chosen to handle their property, however you feel about it. At least in the US, backing up media is not sufficient cause to allow circumvention of DRM, even though you have the legal right to do so under the first sale doctrine. Note however that this right only extends to physical media purchases; digital content is not covered by first sale doctrine (which is why the content industry wants to kill it).

Comment: Personally, I'd look for ways to run DVDecryptor (I know, you are on a mac). It will be able to tell you about the disk format, content protection, etc. Sorry, this is really taking me back, so I'm trying to recall the kinds of tools i used to use. The Alcohol line of products for disk imaging were very useful.

Comment: @FrankThomas As I mentioned earlier, this is not a Video DVD - it is software (so the MPAA doesn't come into the picture), and the enclosed license specifically states one may make (1) copy for backup purposes. Thanks for the software suggestion, but I would prefer a solution using software that just came with the mac..

Comment: @SirAdelaide I have only this laptop. I will try using someone else's. Disk utility in earlier versions of OSX was useful. The current version in El Capitan seems like it has been lobotomised.

Answer (score 0):

Disk utility just doesn't support "protected" disks (so says [cnet](https://www.cnet.com/news/need-a-copy-of-your-dvd-mac-os-x-does-that/) too).

But you should be able to use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) and libdvdcss (see [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html) or [Macworld DVD ripping FAQ](http://www.macworld.com/article/1150731/software/dvdripping-faqs.html)) instead. See Macworld's [VIDEO: How to rip a DVD with HandBrake](http://www.macworld.com/article/1157590/how_to_rip_dvd_handbrake.html) or [Macworld UK article: How to rip a DVD or Blu-ray Disc to Mac](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-rip-dvd-to-mac-apple-3634696/) for more info, basically just install Handbrake & it'll ask you about installing libdvdcss.pkg, then put in a DVD & you're rolling.

Comment: how do I know if a disk is protected ? Is there some terminal command I could use ?

Comment: Now that I don't know, I'd search the web for that answer. But, any program that can copy protected dvd's should be just as good at copying unprotected dvd's, so just use that program for both